# Writing a matrix to a text file

Tags: vb.net, matrix, ruby-on-rails-3.2, text-files, cocoa-bindings

So i have done how to read a matrix from a text file where the first line defines the elements, however my question is how would i do the opposite that would write to the text file. I would like it to ask the user for the row 0 column 0, and add on, and have this code to write into the console, but do not know how to do into a text file

This is the code to write into console:

```
Dim size As Integer = 3
Dim numberWidth As Integer = 2
Dim format As String = "D" & numberWidth

Dim A(size - 1, size - 1) As Integer
For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
    For j As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
        Console.Write(String.Format("Enter The Matrix Element at A[Row {0}, Col {1}]: ", i, j))
        A(i, j) = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine())
    Next
Next
```

This is code for reading the matrix

```
Dim path = "d:\matrix.txt"
Dim A(,) As Integer
Using reader As New IO.StreamReader(path)
    Dim size = reader.ReadLine() ' read first line which is the size of the matrix (assume the matrix is a square)
    Redim A(size - 1, size - 1)

    Dim j = 0 ' the current line in the matrix
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine() ' read next line
    Do While (line <> Nothing) ' loop as long as line is not empty
        Dim numbers = line.Split(" ") ' split the numbers in that line
        For i = 0 To numbers.Length - 1
            A(j, i) = numbers(i) ' copy the numbers into the matrix in current line
        Next

        j += 1 ' increment the current line
        line = reader.ReadLine() ' read next line
    Loop
End Using

Console.WriteLine("Matrix A :")
Dim numberWidth As Integer = 2
Dim format As String = "D" & numberWidth
For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
    Console.Write("| ")
    For j As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
        Console.Write("{0} ", A(i, j).ToString(format))
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("|")
Next
```

Save function:

```
    Dim A(,) As Integer
Sub SaveMatrix()
    Dim path As String = "z:\matrix.txt"







    Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(path, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        fs.SetLength(0) ' reset file length to 0 in case we are overwriting an existing file
        Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(fs)
            Dim line As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            sw.WriteLine((A.GetUpperBound(0) + 1).ToString()) ' size of array in first line
            For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
                line.Clear()
                For j As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
                    line.Append(A(i, j).ToString() & " ")
                Next
                sw.WriteLine(line.ToString().Trim()) ' output each row to the file
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("Matrix successfully saved to:")
    Console.WriteLine(path)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a framework to build upon demonstrating how to enter, save, and load your matrices.  You can add other options to the menu based on what other operations you need to implement:

```vb
Module Module1

    Public A(,) As Integer

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim response As String
        Dim quit As Boolean = False
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("")
            Console.WriteLine("--- Menu Options ---")
            Console.WriteLine("1) Enter a Matrix")
            Console.WriteLine("2) Display Matrix")
            Console.WriteLine("3) Save Matrix")
            Console.WriteLine("4) Load Matrix")
            Console.WriteLine("5) Quit")
            Console.Write("Menu choice: ")
            response = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("")
            Select Case response
                Case "1"
                    EnterMatrix()

                Case "2"
                    DisplayMatrix()

                Case "3"
                    SaveMatrix()

                Case "4"
                    LoadMatrix()

                Case "5"
                    quit = True

                Case Else
                    Console.WriteLine("")
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Menu Choice")

            End Select
        Loop While (Not quit)

        Console.Write("Press any key to dismiss the console...")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Public Sub EnterMatrix()
        Dim valid As Boolean
        Dim size, value As Integer
        Console.Write("Enter the Size of the Square Matrix: ")
        Dim response As String = Console.ReadLine()
        If Integer.TryParse(response, size) Then
            If size >= 2 Then
                Console.WriteLine("")
                ReDim A(size - 1, size - 1)
                For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
                    Console.WriteLine("--- Row " & i & " ---")
                    For j As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
                        valid = False
                        Do
                            Console.Write(String.Format("Enter The Matrix Element at A[Row {0}, Col {1}]: ", i, j))
                            response = Console.ReadLine()
                            If Integer.TryParse(response, value) Then
                                A(i, j) = value
                                valid = True
                            Else
                                Console.WriteLine("")
                                Console.WriteLine("Matrix Element must be a valid Integer!")
                                Console.WriteLine("")
                            End If
                        Loop While (Not valid)
                    Next
                    Console.WriteLine("")
                Next
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("")
                Console.WriteLine("Size must be greater than or equal to 2!")
            End If
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("")
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Size")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub DisplayMatrix()
        If Not IsNothing(A) AndAlso A.Length > 0 Then
            Dim maxLength As Integer = Integer.MinValue
            For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
                For j As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
                    maxLength = Math.Max(maxLength, A(i, j).ToString.Length)
                Next
            Next

            Console.WriteLine("Matrix Contents:")
            For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
                Console.Write("| ")
                For j As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
                    Console.Write("{0} ", A(i, j).ToString().PadLeft(maxLength, " "))
                Next
                Console.WriteLine("|")
            Next
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("The Matrix is empty!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub SaveMatrix()
        If Not IsNothing(A) AndAlso A.Length > 0 Then
            Console.Write("Enter the name of the File to Save To (example: `Matrix.txt`): ")
            Dim response As String = Console.ReadLine()
            Dim fullPathFileName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, response)
            Try
                If System.IO.File.Exists(fullPathFileName) Then
                    Console.WriteLine("")
                    Console.WriteLine("There is already a file at:")
                    Console.WriteLine(fullPathFileName)
                    Console.WriteLine("")
                    Console.Write("Would you like to overwrite it? Enter 'Y' or 'YES' to confirm: ")
                    response = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper
                    If response <> "Y" AndAlso response <> "YES" Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
                Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(fullPathFileName, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                    fs.SetLength(0) ' reset file length to 0 in case we are overwriting an existing file
                    Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(fs)
                        Dim line As New System.Text.StringBuilder
                        sw.WriteLine((A.GetUpperBound(0) + 1).ToString()) ' size of array in first line
                        For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
                            line.Clear()
                            For j As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
                                line.Append(A(i, j).ToString() & " ")
                            Next
                            sw.WriteLine(line.ToString().Trim()) ' output each row to the file
                        Next
                    End Using
                End Using
                Console.WriteLine("")
                Console.WriteLine("Matrix successfully saved to:")
                Console.WriteLine(fullPathFileName)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("")
                Console.WriteLine("Error Saving Matrix!")
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("The Matrix is empty!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadMatrix()
        Console.Write("Enter the name of the File to Load From (example: `Matrix.txt`): ")
        Dim response As String = Console.ReadLine()
        Try
            Dim A2(,) As Integer

            Dim line As String
            Dim value As Integer
            Dim values() As String
            Dim arraySize As Integer
            Dim fullPathFileName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, response)
            Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(fullPathFileName)
                line = sr.ReadLine ' get matrix size and convert it to an int
                If Integer.TryParse(line, value) Then
                    arraySize = value
                    ReDim A2(arraySize - 1, arraySize - 1)
                    For row As Integer = 0 To arraySize - 1
                        values = sr.ReadLine().Trim().Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        If values.Length = arraySize Then
                            For col As Integer = 0 To arraySize - 1
                                If Integer.TryParse(values(col).Trim, value) Then
                                    A2(row, col) = value
                                Else
                                    Console.WriteLine("")
                                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Element in file!")
                                    Exit Sub
                                End If
                            Next
                        Else
                            Console.WriteLine("")
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Row Size in file!")
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    Next
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("")
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Matrix Size in first line of file!")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End Using
            A = A2
            Console.WriteLine("")
            Console.WriteLine("Matrix successfully loaded from:")
            Console.WriteLine(fullPathFileName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("")
            Console.WriteLine("Error Loading Matrix!")
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you idle_mind, quick question though, say if i don't want user to enter/modify the destination of the file or change the name as i am using it on another program how would i go around that, i tried to do this please see code above, let me know what i need to fix, thanks

Comment: You've got the right idea, then, just hard code a fixed filename with path and use that instead.  Give it a shot...you can do it!

Comment: i tried it last night b4 messaging you and posted the code, didnt work, revisied it today still nothing, help please

Comment: Define "didn't work".  **What** doesn't work, exactly?  What **errors**, if any, are you getting?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Great. ..but what **line** does it point to  when this error occurs?  I can't see your screen my friend.  I want to help; give me something to work with.

Comment: My best guess is you've declared the array a second time **inside** the save method.  If so, get rid of the `Dim A(,) As Integer` line in the method.  It should be declared outside of all methods, at Class/Form level.

Comment: tried that have this System.IO.File.WriteAllText( underlined in red now.

Comment: You're putting two pieces of code together.  My examples never used `WriteAllText()`, Mary's did (but only in one of her comments).  In my save routine, I'm using a **FileStream**.  Change to `Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(fullPathFileName, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)`.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ive tried it again check my code, still this error can you help me please

Comment: Same line with that error?... or somewhere else now? I might need to see all of your code as a whole to figure it out.

Comment: ive put it in, i just used a new console, its literally just that code, no error on code just when running it

Comment: Literally, just that code?  Look closely at my SaveMatrix() example. It has an extra check in there to make sure you're not trying to save an **empty** matrix.  It's the very first line of code in that method...

Comment: i am very confused, i just want a preset location which i can define, where then the user is asked the array dimension then the values in the format of the last matrix thing we did, in the file want it the same way.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the filename, it's from the **Matrix** not having any data in it.   If you only have that code, as you say,  then the matrix is **empty** and will generate that error if you don't have the extra checks I mentioned.  Run the FULL demo app I posted. Use the option to enter data before you try to save it!

Comment: when i run your code to save the matrix, i just get told that the matrix is empty?

Comment: ... and did you follow my instructions that told you to select the option to enter some data **FIRST**, before selecting the save option?!  Look, the declaration of the matrix is `Dim A(,) As Integer`, which is an EMPTY MATRIX. If you don't take action to put data into an empty matrix, then you still have an empty matrix...

Comment: once again smashed it, i understand now, sorry so new to this, thank you for being patient bro, did you manage to win the board game yesterday,

Comment: wish you could run for prime minister, why, because you solve uncertainty, what is uncertainty: something you solve!

Comment: Glad you finally understand and have some working code.  Be sure to upvote or accept any posts, from anyone, that you found helpful.

Comment: i always try to upvote, unlike some like mary who always downvotes, but it does not register because i have low ranking, don't worry, i always upvote yours bro

Answer (score 1):

I have created a class for the Matrix data and the a List(of T) so you con't have to worry about changing the size of an array.

I am using Interpolated strings which is a replacement for String.Format in some cases and easier to read.

I have overriden the .ToString method in the MatrixItem class to make it easy to save the objects to a text file.

Other comments in-line.

```vb
Public Sub Main()
    Dim A As List(Of MatrixItem) = CreateListOfMatrixItem()
    SaveMatrixList(A)
    ViewMatrixFile()
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Function CreateListOfMatrixItem() As List(Of MatrixItem)
    Dim A As New List(Of MatrixItem)
    Dim HowManyRows As Integer = 3
    For i As Integer = 0 To HowManyRows - 1
        Dim M As New MatrixItem()
        For j As Integer = 0 To 2
            Console.WriteLine($"Enter The Matrix Element at A[Row {i}, Col {j}]: ")
            Select Case j
                Case 0
                    M.X = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine())
                Case 1
                    M.Y = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine())
                Case 2
                    M.Z = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine())
            End Select
        Next
        A.Add(M)
    Next
    Return A
End Function

Private Sub SaveMatrixList(A As List(Of MatrixItem))
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each item In A
        sb.AppendLine(item.ToString)
    Next
    'this will open or create the file and append the new data
    'if you want to overwrite the contents of the file then 
    'use File.WriteAllText("Matrix.txt", sb.ToString)
    File.AppendAllText("Matrix.txt", sb.ToString)
End Sub

Private Sub ViewMatrixFile()
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("Matrix.txt")
    Console.WriteLine($"{"X",10}{"Y",10}{"Z",10}")
    For Each line In lines
        Dim numbers = line.Split(","c)
        'To format the values with the a numeric format it is necessary to convert the
        'strings to a numeric type.
        Console.WriteLine($"{CInt(numbers(0)),10:D2}{CInt(numbers(1)),10:D2}{CInt(numbers(2)),10:D2}")
    Next
End Sub

Public Class MatrixItem
    Public Property X As Int16
    Public Property Y As Int16
    Public Property Z As Int16
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{X},{Y},{Z}"
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: @loco3424 I see you are trying to use Z:\ Is this a mapped drive? There are some issues with mapped drives as the are user dependent.